# parallel - output to different directory

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am trying to use parallel this way :

```
find /root/Output/ -type f -name *.out | parallel --pipe --round-robin -j 9 programm.py --worker_threads 72 -o output_dir
```

I would like to save the output of each job into separate directory.
Running parallel this way, programm.py write results from different job in the same directory/files causing problems for some lines in specific files I need for downstream analysis.

How can I achieve this ? 
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Make a directory for each job based on the job number `{#}` maybe:

```
find ... | parallel --pipe --round-robin -j 9 'mkdir -p {#} ; cd {#} ; programm.py --worker_threads 72'
```

Comment: I cannot change programm.py, I have to specify output directory. I will try your solution and let you know if it work

Comment: You can hopefully use `-o .` or `-o "$(pwd)"`